# How to install and run compass with rvm and gem?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, installation, rvm

OS: Mint Linux 11 64bit

I know nothing about ruby, I just want Compass.

I've installed rvm and ruby 1.9.3, and set the default ruby

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I've installed compass via gem

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.3)
chunky_png (1.2.5)
compass (0.12.1)
fssm (0.2.8.1)
rake (0.9.2)
rubygems-bundler (0.2.8)
sass (3.1.15)
```

But I cannot run **compass**, because gem/bin is not in $PATH

I added it to $PATH and run compass again:

```
$ compass
/home/il/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find compass (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/il/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /home/il/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1230:in `gem'
from /home/il/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/compass:18:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: could you please explain, how you have managed to run your compass project? When I try to run the compass commands it shows me the compass help..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$ rvm wrapper 1.9.3@compass --no-prefix compass`

Comment: Thank you iron9light, that worked! people starting to work with ruby may want to read about rmv gemsets https://rvm.io/gemsets/, you should use that as best practice to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 11):

assuming that rvm is installed you could do something like:

```
$ rvm install 2.1.1
$ rvm @global do gem install compass
```

No need to do sudo.