# Compass no longer working after ruby update

Tags: ruby, rvm, compass-sass

After installing RVM the other day I can no longer use `compass watch` as I could.

I've tried updating the system, installing compass again, as well as sass, all to no avail.

Here's the error I get in Terminal:

```
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build': /Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've attempted to use `bundle update sass-rails` per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157879/cannot-execute-compass-because-of-sass-version), but get the error `Could not locate Gemfile`

I've also tried to follow [the advise here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904389/how-to-install-and-run-compass-with-rvm-and-gem) to no avail.

At this point I'm a bit lost. I'm brand new to the Ruby world as well as RVM, and am not the most proficient Terminal user to begin with.

Thanks for any assistance or insight-

Answer (score 3):

`/Gemfile not found` was a bug in older version of `rubygems-bundler` gem, run:

```
rvm @global do gem update rubygems-bundler
```

and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer as to how to fix the problem itself, but I did go through with simply removing it for the time being.

I used `rvm implode` to remove `rvm` from my machine per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950260/howto-uninstall-rvm).

Everything worked fine after that. Unfortunately that'll delay my experimenting with the Ruby world for a little while longer as I don't have time to figure out how to have RVM without the complications it seemingly brought.

Best,